# Windows phone bind data from two separate classes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

My goal is to show in ListBox with Datatemplate and two TextBlocks: user message text and user name.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageText}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I have two separate classes generated and parsed from json response into lists:

```
Message
{
   int MessageID;
   string MessageText;
   int UserID;
}
User
{
   int UserID;
   string UserName;
}

List<Message> Messages;
List<User> Users;
```

How could I bind in xaml `UserName` from class `User` next to user message from class `Message`? Both classes have `UserId` which is identical.

Of course, the easy way to go would be create additional property `UserName` in `Message` class and then pass `UserName` property from User class into `Message` and then bind it, but that seems repetitive task and bad practice.

One solution that came to mind is to use some kind of value converter and then pass additional params like `UserId` and User List, but that seems kind of hackish.. So I wonder if there is some kind of linq, sql style implementation to get my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
   Message mess = null; 

   var item = from user in Users
              where (mess = Messages.First(m => m.UserID == user.UserID)) != null
              select new {user.UserName, mess.MessageText};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me by now :) with linq i can make a query from Json.net JObject and directly pass properties to Message class.

Answer (score 3):

Either one of your workaround you mention will work and I don't think there is anyway to bind to two different object. The reason lies in the way .NET data binding works. It uses the first object to determine the properties and then expects the rest to follow.

Personally, I would create another class that contains User and Message and then "forward call" when needed. Obviously, when you create this class, you make sure to put the User and Message with the matching ID together.

for instance,

```
class Chat
    {
        private User user;

        private Message message;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return user.Username;
            }
        }

        public string MessageText
        {
            get
            {
                return message.MessageText;
            }
        }
    }
```

ref: [community.devexpress](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/30797.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using your predefined classes you can do this also.

```
public class DisplayBox
{
    public User user{get;set}

    public Message message{get;set;}
}
```

Now create a `public List<DisplayBox> list = new List();`

And add items to it.

```
   list.Add(new DisplayBox()
   {
        user = new User(){UserName=""}, message = new Message(){Message=""}
   });
```

Now bind your listbox to this list.

```
 <ListBox ItemSource={Binding list}
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding message.MessageText}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding user.UserName}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I hope it helps.